# Using tap gesture and long press at the same time in Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm building a table view and I cannot seem to get both regular taps and long presses to work.

I have placed this code in my viewDidLoad:

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
myTableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

and this code is my gesture recognizer:

```
@objc func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if UILongPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {

        let touchPoint = UILongPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.myTableView)
        if let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touchPoint) {
            print(indexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

I have found this code here on Stack Overflow, but I do not think it is up to date for Swift 4 because I can not even run it without the build failing.

Comment: `if sender.state == .began {` and `let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.myTableView)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer.state` should be `sender.state` and `UILongPressGesutreRecognizer.location` should be `sender.location`. Also, the signature for `indexPathForRowAtPoint()` has been updated to `indexPathForRow(at:)`.

Corrrected code:

```
@objc func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {
        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.myTableView)
        if let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForRow(at:touchPoint) {
            print(indexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is a class name, you need to be calling the class instance.

Comment: the syntax have changed a bit for  Swift 4  `func indexPathForRow(at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath?` so `if let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {`